# Why are my Google Maps V3 Markers centered in the screen and not positioned on their geolocation?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

For my site(asp.net vb), I'm making an interactive Google Maps page, where markers are loaded off an XML file. When I made the code and tested it localhost it all worked fine. Now I uploaded everything to the server and all my markers are misplaced and I can't seem to get to the problem. Maybe anyone got the same problem or knows what I'm doing wrong?

My map can be viewed here: http://beta.groundhoppen.nl/kaart

My code:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // Set map height to match viewport
        var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();
        viewportHeight = viewportHeight - 60;
        $("#maps").css({ 'height': viewportHeight }, 0);
        $(window).resize(function () {
            var viewportHeight = window.innerHeight ? window.innerHeight : $(window).height();
            viewportHeight = viewportHeight - 60;
            $("#maps").css({ 'height': viewportHeight }, 0);
        });
        $("body").css("overflow", "hidden");

        // Filter tabs
        $("#filter > div").hide();
        $("#filter > div:first").show();
        $("#filter > ul li a").click(function () {
            if ($(this).parent().hasClass("active")) {
                return false;
            } else {
                var index = $(this).parent().index() + 5;
                $("#filter > ul li").removeClass("active");
                $(this).parent().addClass("active");
                $("#filter > div").slideUp(250);
                $("#filter > div:nth-child(" + index + ")").slideDown(250);
                if ($("#filter > div:nth-child(" + index + ")").attr("id") == "search") {
                    $("#search .input").focus();
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

        // Drag info and filter
        $("#filter").draggable({ containment: "#maps", scroll: false, handle: ".move" });
        $("#stadium-info").draggable({ containment: "#maps", scroll: false, handle: ".move" });

        // Hide info
        $('#stadium-info').hide();

        // Info closed
        $('.close').click(function () {
            var val = $(this).attr('rel');
            markers[val].setMap(map);
            unlock();
            $('#stadium-info').fadeOut(500);
            $('#filter').delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
            return false;
        });

        $('.next, .prev').live('click', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            var id = $(this).attr('rel');
            google.maps.event.trigger(markers[id], 'click');
        });
    });


    // Calculate best zoom for displaysize
    var startZoom = null;
    var viewportWidth = window.innerWidth ? window.innerWidth : $(window).width();
    if (viewportWidth >= 1920) {
        startZoom = 3;
    } else {
        startZoom = 2;
    }

    // Map options
    var markers = [];
    var emptyZoom = 17;
    var startPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(10.0, 28.652344);
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: startZoom,
        center: startPosition,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE,
        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        minZoom: startZoom,
        zoomControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
        },
        panControlOptions: {
            position: google.maps.ControlPosition.RIGHT_TOP
        }
    };
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("google-maps"), mapOptions);

    // Lock map
    function lock() {
        map.setOptions({
            disableDoubleClickZoom: true,
            draggable: false,
            zoomControl: false,
            panControl: false,
            scrollwheel: false
        });
    }

    // Unlock map
    function unlock() {
        map.setOptions({
            disableDoubleClickZoom: false,
            draggable: true,
            zoomControl: true,
            panControl: true,
            scrollwheel: true
        });
    }

    // Vars lat lng zoom for infobox
    var oldLat = null;
    var oldLng = null;
    var oldZoom = null;

    // Create markers
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "xml/Maps.xml",
        dataType: "xml",
        success: function (xml) {
            $(xml).find('stadium').each(function () {
                var lat = $(this).attr('latitude');
                var lng = $(this).attr('longitude');
                var zoom = $(this).attr('zoom');
                var name = $(this).attr('name');
                var id = $(this).attr('id');
                var countryId = $(this).parent().attr('id');

                if (lat > 0 || lat < 0) {
                    if (zoom == 0) {
                        zoom = emptyZoom;
                    }
                    var point = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng)
                    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                        position: point,
                        map: map,
                        icon: 'img/bg/icon-stadium.png',
                        title: name
                    });
                    marker.metadata = { id: id, name: name, countryId: countryId };
                    markers[id] = marker;
                    // Marker click function
                    google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function () {
                        // Save current lat lng zoom to cookie

                        //alert(map.getZoom());


                        // Zoom in on marker and hide marker                    
                        offset = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, parseFloat(lng) + parseFloat(0.0015));
                        map.panTo(offset);
                        map.setZoom(parseInt(zoom));
                        lock();
                        marker.setMap(null);

                        // Hide filter
                        $('#filter').fadeOut(500);

                        // Determine info position
                        var right;
                        if (viewportWidth > 1280) {
                            right = viewportWidth - 960;
                            right = right / 2 - 10;
                        } else {
                            right = 30;
                        }

                        // Get marker id
                        var id = marker.metadata.id;

                        $.ajax({
                            type: "GET",
                            url: "xml/Maps.xml",
                            dataType: "xml",
                            success: function (xml) {
                                var flag = $(xml).find("stadium[id=" + id + "]").parent().attr('flag');
                                var club = $(xml).find("stadium[id=" + id + "]").attr('club');
                                var capacity = $(xml).find("stadium[id=" + id + "]").attr('capacity');
                                var constructed = $(xml).find("stadium[id=" + id + "]").attr('constructed');
                                var inuse = $(xml).find("stadium[id=" + id + "]").attr('inuse');
                                var countryid = $(xml).find("stadium[id=" + id + "]").parent().attr('id');
                                var countryname = $(xml).find("stadium[id=" + id + "]").parent().attr('name');
                                var nextstadiumname = $(xml).find("stadium[id=" + id + "]").next().attr('name');
                                var nextstadiumclub = $(xml).find("stadium[id=" + id + "]").next().attr('club');
                                var nextstadiumid = $(xml).find("stadium[id=" + id + "]").next().attr('id');
                                var prevstadiumname = $(xml).find("stadium[id=" + id + "]").prev().attr('name');
                                var prevstadiumclub = $(xml).find("stadium[id=" + id + "]").prev().attr('club');
                                var prevstadiumid = $(xml).find("stadium[id=" + id + "]").prev().attr('id');
                                var rating = parseFloat($(xml).find("stadium[id=" + id + "]").attr('rating'));

                                $('#stadium-info a.close').attr("rel", id);
                                $('#stadium-info h6:first').html(name).prepend('<img src="uploads/flags/' + flag + '.png" alt="' + countryname + '" /> ');
                                $('#stadium-info').css('right', right).delay(1000).fadeIn(500);
                                if (nextstadiumname == undefined) {
                                    nextstadiumname = $(xml).find("country[id=" + countryid + "]").children().first().attr('name');
                                    nextstadiumclub = $(xml).find("country[id=" + countryid + "]").children().first().attr('club');
                                    nextstadiumid = $(xml).find("country[id=" + countryid + "]").children().first().attr('id');
                                }
                                $('.next').html(nextstadiumname);
                                $('.next').attr('title', nextstadiumname + ', ' + nextstadiumclub);
                                $('.next').attr('rel', nextstadiumid);
                                if (prevstadiumname == undefined) {
                                    prevstadiumname = $(xml).find("country[id=" + countryid + "]").children().last().attr('name');
                                    prevstadiumclub = $(xml).find("country[id=" + countryid + "]").children().last().attr('club');
                                    prevstadiumid = $(xml).find("country[id=" + countryid + "]").children().last().attr('id');
                                }
                                $('.prev').html(prevstadiumname);
                                $('.prev').attr('title', prevstadiumname + ', ' + prevstadiumclub);
                                $('.prev').attr('rel', prevstadiumid);
                                $('#info-capacity').html(capacity);
                                $('#info-club').html(club.replace(/_/g, "<br />"));
                                $('#info-constructed').html(constructed);
                                $('#info-inuse').html(inuse);
                                var oRating = $find("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder2_GoogleMaps1_rating");
                                oRating.set_value(rating);
                            }
                        });
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });

    //Filters

    // Reset filters and show all markers
    function ResetFilters() {
        $("#search .input").val("Zoek op trefwoord");
        ResetMarkers();
    }
    // Reset all markers to map
    function ResetMarkers() {
        for (i in markers) {
            markers[i].setMap(map);
        }
    }

    // Filter by country
    $("#filter_country").live("change", function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: "xml/Maps.xml",
            dataType: "xml",
            success: function (xml) {
                var lat = $(xml).find("country[id=" + val + "]").attr("latitude");
                var lng = $(xml).find("country[id=" + val + "]").attr("longitude");
                var zoom = $(xml).find("country[id=" + val + "]").attr("zoom");
                if (lat > "0" && lng > "0") {
                    var countryPosition = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
                    map.panTo(countryPosition);
                    map.setZoom(parseInt(zoom));
                }
            }
        });


        if (val > 0) {
            for (i in markers) {
                if (markers[i].metadata.countryId == val) {
                    markers[i].setMap(map);
                } else {
                    markers[i].setMap(null);
                }
            }
        } else {
            ResetMarkers();
        }
    });

    // Filter by stadium
    $("#filter_stadium").live("change", function () {
        var val = $(this).val();
        //var marker = new google.maps.Marker(markers[val]);
        google.maps.event.trigger(markers[val], 'click');
    });

    // Filter by keywords
    $("#search .input").keyup(function () {
        var val = $(this).val().toLowerCase();
        if (val != "suche nach schlüsselwort" && val != "search by keyword" && val != "zoek op trefwoord") {
            for (i in markers) {
                if (markers[i].metadata.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(val) >= 0) {
                    markers[i].setMap(map);
                } else {
                    markers[i].setMap(null);
                }
            }
        } else {
            ResetMarkers();
        }
    });
    $('#search .input').focus(function () {
        map.setCenter(startPosition);
        map.setZoom(startZoom);
    });


    $("#filter ul li a").click(function () {
        ResetFilters();
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: Are they all shown in the middle of the Ocean? If so, the lng/lat is probably not set or 0/0.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your data at http://beta.groundhoppen.nl/xml/Maps.xml -- there are a number of locations at (0,0) and all of them are within only a few degrees of that point.

Comment: Your right, how stupid of me not to see that. I know now where the problem is, in my function that creates my maps.xml. This function removes parts of the latitude and longitude. And indeed then uses values of 6.xx wich are all close to 0.0